# Count of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table (`student`) is structured like this:

```
NAME    ACCOUNT SALARY
a         12     1222
b        113     222222
c         21     2221
d         12     2432
```

I want to show results like this:

[image: Desired Results]

How do I get to select the distinct account count?

Answer (score 1):

You would use window functions:

```
select name, account, salary,
       count(*) over (partition by account) as account_count
from student;
```

This is not only the simplest way to express the query; it should also have the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  `NAME`
  ,`ACCOUNT`
  ,`SALARY`
  , (SELECT count(*) FROM abc WHERE `ACCOUNT` = a.`ACCOUNT` ) AS 'ACCOUNT COUNT'
   FROM abc a;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB []> SELECT
    ->   `NAME`
    ->   ,`ACCOUNT`
    ->   ,`SALARY`
    ->   , (SELECT count(*) FROM abc WHERE `ACCOUNT` = a.`ACCOUNT` ) AS 'ACCOUNT COUNT'
    ->    FROM abc a;
+------+---------+--------+---------------+
| NAME | ACCOUNT | SALARY | ACCOUNT COUNT |
+------+---------+--------+---------------+
| a    | 12      |   1222 |             2 |
| b    | 113     | 222222 |             1 |
| c    | 21      |   2221 |             1 |
| d    | 12      |   2432 |             2 |
+------+---------+--------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```